# How does Field Analyzer and tokenizer work in solr

Tags: solr

I want to know the uses and example of the Field Analyzer and Tokenizer in SOLR 9

What is new in SOLR 9

Comment: What are you looking for about these concepts? What is it that you don't understand? What have you tried and failed with? The reference guide attempts to explain the relevant concepts: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/document-analysis.html, https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/analyzers.html, https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/tokenizers.html, https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html